# Can't receive data from axios on API

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I have an axios post request on my Vue frontend which sends some data to an API endpoint (express). The problem is that I can't see any data on the controller that receive the post request.

```
//app.js

var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.port || 1337

app.use(cors({origin: true}));
var imagenmatriculaController = require('./controllers/imagenmatriculaController.js')()

app.use("/api/imagenmatricula", imagenmatriculaController)

app.listen(port, function () {})


//imagenmatriculaController.js

var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var routes = function (){
    router.route('/')
        .post(function(req,res){

            console.log(req.data)
            res.json('ok')
        })
        return router
}

module.exports = routes
```

I do receive the request log on the server and the 'ok' back to the client but I get an undefined on the console.log(req.data);

```
//vue post

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
};

axios.post('http://localhost:1337/api/imagenmatricula', {
                    headers: headers,
                    data: 'test'
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log('ERROR::', error.response.data);
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive json data on backend you need to setup parser. You could use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions). Then your code should look like this

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.port || 1337
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(cors({origin: true}));
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var imagenmatriculaController = require('./controllers/imagenmatriculaController.js')()

app.use("/api/imagenmatricula", imagenmatriculaController)

app.listen(port, function () {})


//imagenmatriculaController.js

var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var routes = function (){
    router.route('/')
        .post(function(req,res){

            console.log(req.body)
            res.json('ok')
        })
        return router
}

module.exports = routes
```

Client should look like this:

```
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
};

    axios.post('http://localhost:1337/api/imagenmatricula', {
                        headers: headers,
                        data: { test: 'test' }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log('ERROR::', error.response.body);
                    });
```

If your routing on server is correctly setup, this should work.

Comment: As of **Express v4.16.0** there is no need to use *body-parser* if you are going to parse`json` or `urlencoded` payloads. Parsing these two are now implemented as built-in middlewares: [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) and [express.urlencoded()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have body-parser in order to use json data in node and express. So in order to make your code work. First install body-parser through 'npm install body-parser' command then use it as middleware in your code as shown below:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.port || 1337
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(cors({origin: true}));

//It will parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

//It will parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var imagenmatriculaController = require('./controllers/imagenmatriculaController.js')()

app.use("/api/imagenmatricula", imagenmatriculaController)

app.listen(port, function () {})
```

In imagenmatriculaController.js write,

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var routes = function (){
    router.route('/')
        .post(function(req,res){

            console.log(req.body)
            res.json('ok')
        })
        return router
}

module.exports = routes
```

Your front end client should contain following code:

```
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
};

    axios.post('http://localhost:1337/api/imagenmatricula', {
                        headers: headers,
                        data: { test: 'test' }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log('ERROR::', error.response.body);
                    });
```

Note:: If you are using higher version of express i.e v4.16.0 then instead of using `bodyParser.json()` and `bodyParser.urlencoded()` you can use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` because it is built-in middleware of express from version v4.16.0. So choose wisely,

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```